# How to count on DISTINCT ON without subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to implement paging where it gets the last profile with a specific email that hasn't been verified. I don't understand why this query fails with

> column "profile.email" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
>   be used in an aggregate function

```
select distinct ON (email) email, count(*) 
from "profile" where "verified" = false 
order by "email" asc, "created_date" asc limit 1
```

but this one works

```
select distinct ON (email) email, * 
from "profile" where "verified" = false 
order by "email" asc, "created_date" asc limit 10
```

Is there any way for me to address this without using subqueries?

**Edit**

After some testing the given answer does not appear to be correct.

```
select distinct ON (email) email, count(*) over()
from "profile" 
where "email" = 'example@test.com' 
order by "email" desc, "created_date" desc limit 1
```

returns (incorrect)

> [{email: 'example@test.com',count:18 }]

```
select distinct ON (email) email
from "profile" 
where "email" = 'example@test.com' 
order by "email" desc, "created_date" desc limit 10
```

returns (correct)

> [{email: 'example@test.com'}]

Comment: I don't have a solution. This given answer was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function:

```
select distinct ON (email) email, count(*) over ()
from "profile"
where "verified" = false 
order by "email" asc, "created_date" asc
limit 1
```

For this example, I don't know what advantage that has over:

```
select email, count(*) over ()
from "profile"
where "verified" = false 
order by "created_date" asc
limit 1
```

Comment: Regarding your second query. Would it still work if there the limit is greater than 1?

Comment: @als9xd . . . No, but that is not the question that you asked.

Comment: Sorry I updated it. I need a greater limit for pagination. Also I'm using this in a generalized function where sometimes I don't need to get distinct on and a regular `count()` will do. Is there a significant performance impact to use this in place of all `counts()` even if they don't strictly require it?

Comment: I did some testing and I think your query is incorrect. I have updated my question with the results.